# Can an App intercept network traffic of another app?

Tags: android, json, http, https, get

My android app sends a GET request with some access parameters to a server. The server responds with a json file. **Is there a way for me to get that json file in that moment when it delivered?**

This question was asked because someone can sniff the network traffic of my app and I want to eliminate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in @Pavneet_Singh's answer, applications can't read traffic generated by other applications, unless it's a VPN application, which can read all traffic passing through. The user needs to explicitly accept this. There are examples of network analyzer apps which function like this.

> This question was asked because my app someone sniffs, and I don't know, is there a way to eliminate that.

It sounds like you're worried somone is analyzing the network traffic of your app. Anyone can use a proxy server to analyze the network traffic passing through it, for example using [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). If you do not want this, you can use HTTPS to encrypt your network traffic, and [certificate pinning](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29988/what-is-certificate-pinning) to only make requests when the server has been verified. HTTPS without certificate pinning isn't enough to prevent others from reading traffic sent by your application.

Comment: Thanks @Bertware ! That's what I wanted to hear.

Comment: Certificate pinning is designed to mitigate the least trustworthy CA problem, and is a good idea to implement in virtually every app. However, saying that "HTTPS without certificate pinning isn't enough to prevent others from reading traffic sent by your application" is too strong a statement.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I'm talking about a 3rd person who is in complete control of the network and device, meaning he could install additional certificates etc. This way even HTTPS can be circumvented (Correct me if I'm wrong). This is a default function in Fiddler, for example. For "normal" usage, I would consider HTTPS strong enough.

Comment: Yes, pinning helps mitigate the problem *somewhat* when you can't trust the platform you're on, and specifically helps against the scenario where someone has installed .e.g. a Fiddler cert or some other proxy cert. I suppose I'm just nitpicking, as I said pinning is almost always a good idea and is not particularly hard.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot sniff through other apps' network calls otherwise it is considered as a security breach in OS which is nearly impossible with normal access